# No LAN internet from Router/acces point

Tags: internet

So I want to have WIFI in my room as well as LAN internet directly to my PC. What I have available is:

- LAN cable coming from the Modem to my room.
- network switch
- Router with Wi-Fi and built-in network switch.

When I plug the LAN cable directly to the PC it works 100% good. But when I try connecting through the router the pc doesn't have internet. It does connect the cable but it says that there is no IP assigned.
I tried basically everything to fix it but nothing I tried works. (for example I tried plugging the LAN cable coming from the modem to the switch first, and then to the PC and Router, but then both of them don't have internet)
can you guys please help me!
I provided pictures of the router and network switch.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLk7D.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dBeu.png)

Edit: Problem is fixed. I just replugged everything and it worked. Stil don't know what the problem was but its fine. Also the "router" was an acces point, programmed to be an acces point (it is technically a router, but they turned it into an accces point) So then i had to use the Blue port and not the WAN ports.

Comment: Put the network switch aside for the moment. Plug the LAN cable to your room to a LAN port on the router. Log into the Router and give it a Static IP on your network (find this before starting). Turn DHCP OFF on the Router. When done, restart it (not reset) and test.

Comment: Hey John, after troubleshooting for hours it randomly worked. Thanks for the response though! Btw i plugged the LAN port in the WLAN rather than the LAN. Is this okay as well? everything is working perfectly

Comment: What you have done is fine. Your wireless will have a different subnet but that may be OK for you.

Answer (score 0):

That is the issue. What port on the wireless router you use. I am going to suggest that you do NOT use the WAN port. If you do then when you connect wirelessly you will have a router behind a router. First go in to the wireless router and turn of the DHCP Server. Your main router should do that and if you leave it turned on in the wireless router the computer might pick up a bad IP address. Disable the DHCP server on the wireless router and use the 4 remaining switch ports for everything. At that point it is actually a "Access Point" and is really what you need.

Comment: I dont know i am using the WAN port. i am using the port that is blue on the picture, if you could take a look please. Also the internet and wifi of the second router is finnaly working after hours of problems so unless its a big deal i'd rather keep it like this. What are the negatives of how its setup now? Thanks!

Comment: The only disadvantage is subnet. If this works for you the your setup is fine. There are no other disadvantages.

Comment: There are no huge negatives. As John said anything that connected to the wireless will be on a different network then devices connected to the switch. So sharing between those computers will be impossible. The only other big negative is that you now have a router behind a router which will make things difficult if you ever get in to needing port forwarding of something of the like.

Comment: Yeah i dont use port fowarding or sharing between computers so its no biggie. But lets say i must share with a  computer, can they just connect to the router in my room. We are on the same router then right? is it then possible to share files?